# Boot Ubuntu Server Without GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, boot-manager

I'm in a hurry.  I've searched all around but evidently I'm not looking up the right think or I'm too much of in a rush to recognize anything as my solution.

I've installed Ubuntu Server for something that I need to run in a little while.  I only need it once and while installing I encountered a fatal error installing GRUB.  The problem is that now I don't know how to get into my box.  I have Windows 7 on the other drive but because there is no boot manager setup, it goes straight into Windows7.

I don't need any fancy solutions, I just need a fast way to boot into my Ubuntu Server and hopefully later set it back to auto boot into Windows7 again.

**EDIT**

I've also looked in msconfig and EasyBCD.  Neither of them show my newly installed Ubuntu Server, only my Windows7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair 
Please refer to it for more options.

> The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following
>   disks and boot on it. (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)
>
> Boot-Repair-Disk is a CD starting Boot-Repair automatically. (English
>   only, 32&64bits compatible, based on Debian-live so Wifi drivers are
>   not recent).
>
> Boot-Repair is also included in Ubuntu-Secure-Remix (multi-languages,
>   ok for Wifi, based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, run Boot-Repair from the Dash)
>
> Remark : you can also install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via
>   UnetBootin, LiliUSB or MultiSystem).

Answer (score 2):

install lilo bootloader http://lilo.alioth.debian.org/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which should be able to solve your trouble and repair the broken boot records, so you should be able to boot both systems again.